# A sequential problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here's a fresh one:

State with proper reason whether you can or cannot rearrange the terms of the sequence $1,1,2,2,3,3,\cdots,10,10$ in such a manner that there are exactly $k$ numbers between two $k$'s where $k$ is any integer between $1$ and $10$, that is, $k\in\{1,2,3,\cdots,10\}$.

Comment: I'm confused - If $k$ is the set, then how can there be exactly $k$ numbers?

Comment: it means nothing but for every $k$, $1 \le k \le 10$

Comment: For example if you start with $1$, then you continue like $1,2,1,3,2....$ see that there is exactly $1$ number i.e.$2$ between two $1$'s and exactly $2$ numbers i.e. $1,3$ between the two $2$'s

Comment: So for example, for $1,1,2,2,3,3$ instead of $1,1,2,2,\cdots,10,10$, a solution would be $3,1,2,1,3,2$

Comment: Ok, now can you generalise this for $n$ suppose $2014$. ,? or what algorithm did you use?

Comment: I'm still trying it for $n=10$... I have a conjecture, but I will only post that once I have stated it clearly and proven it.

Comment: is the representation always unique??

Comment: It's possible for $n=3,4$ but not for $n=1,2,5$ (checked by hand by trying all possibilities - needs to be confirmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. It's called a [Langford Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing) (also sometimes called a [Skolem sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkolemSequence.html)), and a Langford pairing for $n$ exists only when $n\equiv 0,3\mod 4$, and since $10\equiv 2\mod 4$, such pairing doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for $N=10$. One can simply write a backtracking
program and check this. The trick is only to make the program efficient
which can be done through some pruning.

The largest $N$ below $10$ for which there is a solution is $N=8$.

Here are several solutions printed out by the program for $N=8$.

> Solution   1 : 1 7 1 2 8 6 2 3 5 7 4 3 6 8 5 4
>   Solution   2 : 1 7 1 2 8 5 2 6 3 7 4 5 3 8 6 4
>   Solution   3 : 1 7 1 2 6 8 2 5 3 7 4 6 3 5 8 4
>   Solution   4 : 1 7 1 2 8 5 2 4 6 7 3 5 4 8 3 6
>   Solution   5 : 1 6 1 8 2 5 7 2 6 3 4 5 8 3 7 4
>   Solution   6 : 1 6 1 7 2 8 5 2 6 3 4 7 5 3 8 4
>   Solution   7 : 1 6 1 8 2 7 4 2 6 5 3 4 8 7 3 5
>   Solution   8 : 1 7 1 8 2 4 6 2 5 7 4 3 8 6 5 3
>   Solution   9 : 1 8 1 5 2 6 7 2 4 5 8 3 6 4 7 3
>   Solution  10 : 1 7 1 6 2 8 5 2 4 7 6 3 5 4 8 3

And here are several solutions for $N=11$.
This is the smallest $N$ above $10$ which gives any solutions.

> Solution   1 : 1 2 1 11 2 3 9 10 4 3 8 5 7 4 6 11 9 5 10 8 7 6
>   Solution   2 : 1 2 1 11 2 3 10 8 4 3 9 7 5 4 6 11 8 10 5 7 9 6
>   Solution   3 : 1 2 1 11 2 3 9 10 4 3 6 7 8 4 5 11 9 6 10 7 5 8
>   Solution   4 : 1 2 1 11 2 3 10 8 4 3 7 9 6 4 5 11 8 10 7 6 5 9
>   Solution   5 : 1 2 1 9 2 3 11 8 10 3 4 5 7 9 6 4 8 5 11 10 7 6
>   Solution   6 : 1 2 1 9 2 3 10 11 7 3 4 8 5 9 6 4 7 10 5 11 8 6
>   Solution   7 : 1 2 1 9 2 3 10 8 11 3 4 7 5 9 6 4 8 10 5 7 11 6
>   Solution   8 : 1 2 1 9 2 3 10 11 7 3 4 6 8 9 5 4 7 10 6 11 5 8
>   Solution   9 : 1 2 1 11 2 3 10 5 9 3 8 4 7 5 6 11 4 10 9 8 7 6
>   Solution  10 : 1 2 1 9 2 3 10 7 11 3 8 4 5 9 6 7 4 10 5 8 11 6